# NGINX SSL handshake error - sslv3 alert certificate expired:SSL alert number 45

Tags: nginx, ssl, dns

I'm using NGINX for a DNS over TLS server.

However Android "private DNS" suddenly stopped working on all devices.

Using kdig still works as expected

```
kdig -d @my.dns.server +tls-ca +tls-host=my.dns.server example.org
```

However Android requests instead fail and I get the following error in NGINX logs

```
SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14094415:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert certificate expired:SSL alert number 45) while SSL handshaking, client: **.**.**.**, server: 0.0.0.0:853
```

The cert is still valid however and I'm not sure why it's throwing this error.

My NGINX SSL config is

```
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.dns.server/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.dns.server/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA";
ssl_handshake_timeout    10s;
ssl_session_cache        shared:SSL:20m;
ssl_session_timeout      4h;
```

Comment: Make sure to have a look at https://letsencrypt.org/2020/12/21/extending-android-compatibility.html  LE Root certificate expired today.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Is there a way to force certbot to use the "ISRG Root X1" alternative chain?

Comment: Based on the link given, yes it seems possible: "What about the alternate chain? Today, some ACME clients are able to instead request an alternate chain, if their user has configured it. We currently provide the option of getting the chain: Subscriber Certificate < – R3 < – ISRG Root X1"

Comment: Yep, I've found it. You can add `--preferred-chain "ISRG Root X1"` to `certbot` CLI command. That works fine now. Thanks again @PatrickMevzek

Comment: You should write an answer based on your discovery and then choose it as best one. However I am not 100% sure your question is on topic here as not related to programming, maybe better on [sf]

Comment: Have a look at https://www.octopuce.fr/letsencrypt-certificate-expiration-consequences/ also. Seems to describe similar problem and gives multiple solutions, including the one you found.

Answer (score 1):

## The Problem:

The DST Root CA X3 certificate, which letsencrypt uses, has expired. They had already started to use the new ISRG Root X1 certificate additionally for multiple years, but some old devices (for example android <  7.1.1) does not know this new certificate. This means these devices cannot use the new certificate and also **should** not be able to use the old one anymore.

But letsencrypt has noticed that many old ssl implementations (including android) don't check if a certificate has expired. So they can still use the old DST Root CA X3 certificate for these devices. Newer ssl implementation can use the new ISRG Root X1 certificate instead.

see: https://letsencrypt.org/2020/12/21/extending-android-compatibility.html

Sadly, some newer ssl implementation (including the android dot client) notice the old expired certificate and abort the ssl-connection, because the certificate has expired. They don't check the new certificate at all. Because of this implementation dependent behaviour, some newer programs don't work, but others work just fine.

## The Solution:

To keep all newer ssl implementation working, you need to use only the new ISRG Root X1 certificate. To do this, you must use the ISRG Root X1 chain. But this will break the compatible with older device, which don't know the new ISRG Root X1 certificate yet.

If you use certbot you can use the following flag `--preferred-chain "ISRG Root X1"`

If you use the caddy webserver you can add the following lines to the beginning of your Caddyfile:

```
{
    preferred_chains {
        root_common_name "ISRG Root X1"
    }
}
```

Comment: There is one more puzzle piece missing in your explanation to complete the mess. The TLS standard allows multiple certificate chains to exist and be served to the client at the same time. The client then iterates over all the certificates until it reaches a trust anchor it likes. Works nice in theory, except that at least OpenSSL had a major bug in the implementation and stopped on the first invalid certificate. So if you want to serve both the old and new chain, make sure the new chain is send first.